# Explained definition of the norm in Ordinary Least Squares

Tags: scikit-learn

I have recently started learning [Scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) and I am not able to understand the below equation. Could anybody please explain?
[image]

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what part you don't understand?

Comment: What is mean 2 in up and down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The norm indicates the Eucleadan norm, which gives the ordinary distance between the points.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)

The subscript 2 with norm sign indicates "square root of the sum of squares".
The superscript 2 indicates sign power.